# How can I attach a log file to my question?

Tags: discussion

I have posted a question: [LibreOffice causes desktop to flicker/crash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246465/libreoffice-causes-desktop-to-flicker-crash)

I searched my computer for log files and found one large file with various x-session errors.
Is it important to post this file, might it be helpful, and how do I attach it to my post?

Thank you!

Comment: You should be reporting those as bug reports, the reason there's no way to attach files here is because this isn't a bug tracker. See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you want to attach files http://pastebin.com/ is the place to go. They give you an URL that you can paste into the question or in a comment.
- Most times it is enough to just search the log file for the relevant parts. That tend to be less than 10 lines since those errors are often repeated and repeated and repeated where we only need an error notice one time to get an answer.

Comment: Although - if someone is actually able to discern the *relevant parts* he possibly doesn't need to post the logs at all ;-)